# babylonjs load glb from php header for hide file path

Tags: php, babylonjs

I want to load a 3D *.glb file with babylonjs from a hidden file path like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Babylon.js Viewer - Display a 3D model</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/viewer/babylon.viewer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <babylon model="https://example.com/view.php?id=blablabla.glb" templates.main.params.fill-screen="true"></babylon>
  </body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id'] != "blablabla.glb") {
    exit();
}
$file = '3dmodel.glb';
if (file_exists($file)) {   
    header('Content-type: model/gltf-binary');  
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');  
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit; 
} 
?>
```

I got this error from the console "Load Error: There was an error loading the model. Unable to load from https://example.com/view.php?id=blablabla.glb: importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefined importMesh has failed JSON parse"

please help me, thanks.

Comment: Are there any messages in the server error log?

Comment: Does the `glb` file exist in the same directory as `index.php`?

Comment: Is your server responding to requests on the example.com domin?

Comment: yes file same dir with view.php, it fine if i load model direct without view.php

Comment: server fine i go https://example.com/view.php?id=blablabla.glb it download 3dmodel,glb

Comment: and in html <babylon model="https://example.com/3dmodel.glb" templates.main.params.fill-screen="true"></babylon> it running well